# grouping objects java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have something like the below :

```
public class MyClass {
private Long stackId
private Long questionId
}
```

A collection of say 100, where the stackid could be duplicate with different questionIds. Its a one to many relationship between stackId and questionId

Is there a **streamy**, java 8 way to convert to the below strcuture :

```
public class MyOtherClass {
private Long stackId
private Collection<Long> questionIds
}
```

Which would be a collection of 25, with each instance having a nested collection of 4 questionIds.

Input :

```
[{1,100},{1,101},{1,102},{1,103},{2,200},{2,201},{2,202},{1,203}]
```

Output

```
[{1, [100,101,102,103]},{2,[200,201,202,203]}]
```

Comment: http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/02/23/java-8-group-by-with-collections/ - convert to a `Map<Long, Collection<Long>>` first, then convert the entries of that map to (the second kind of) `MyClass` instances.

Comment: I still don't understand the *Which would be a collection of 25,* part. Could you expand? Do you want the collection to contain at most 25 elements? What shall we do with the rest?

Comment: @Tunaki the output has less root elements than the input, but then each root element has a one to many relationship with sub elements (questionIds)

Comment: But why 25? Where does this number come from? And why *A collection of say 100*?

Comment: that doesn't matter, the numbers are just chosen to highlight the reduciton. It could be 1million to 1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The straight-forward way with the Stream API involves 2 Stream pipelines:

- The first one creates a temporary `Map<Long, List<Long>>` of `stackId` to `questionIds`. This is done with the [`groupingBy(classifier, downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) collectors where we classify per the `stackId` and values having the same `stackId` are mapped to their `questionId` (with [`mapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-)) and collected into a list with [`toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--).
- The second one converts each entry of that map into a `MyOtherClass` instance and collects that into a list.

Assuming you have a constructor `MyOtherClass(Long stackId, Collection<Long> questionIds)`, a sample code would be:

```
Map<Long, List<Long>> map = 
    list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            MyClass::getStackId,
            Collectors.mapping(MyClass::getQuestionId, Collectors.toList())
        ));

List<MyOtherClass> result = 
    map.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .map(e -> new MyOtherClass(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Using [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library, you could do that in a single Stream pipeline. This library offers a [`pairing`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/MoreCollectors.html#pairing-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.BiFunction-) and [`first`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/MoreCollectors.html#first--) collectors. This enables to pair two collectors and perform a finisher operation on the two collected results:

- The first one only keeps the first `stackId` of the grouped elements (they will all be the same, by construction)
- The second one mapping each element into their `questionId` and collecting into a list.
- The finisher operation just returns a new instance of `MyOtherClass`.

Sample code:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.collectingAndThen;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.mapping;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
import static one.util.streamex.MoreCollectors.first;
import static one.util.streamex.MoreCollectors.pairing;

// ...

Collection<MyOtherClass> result = 
    StreamEx.of(list)
            .groupingBy(
                MyClass::getStackId,
                pairing(
                    collectingAndThen(mapping(MyClass::getStackId, first()), Optional::get),
                    mapping(MyClass::getQuestionId, toList()),
                    MyOtherClass::new
                )
            ).values();
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the in depth answer . Have you used any of the other functinal libs ? https://github.com/akullpp/awesome-java#functional-programming . This http://www.javaslang.io/ looks particualy active/polished.

Comment: @NimChimpsky No, I've never used those (a bit jOOL).

Answer (score 2):

```
List<MyClass> inputs = Arrays.asList(
    new MyClass(1L, 100L),
    new MyClass(1L, 101L),
    new MyClass(1L, 102L),
    new MyClass(1L, 103L),
    new MyClass(2L, 200L),
    new MyClass(2L, 201L),
    new MyClass(2L, 202L),
    new MyClass(2L, 203L)
);

Map<Long, List<Long>> result = inputs
    .stream()
    .collect(
      Collectors.groupingBy(MyClass::getStackId,
        Collectors.mapping(
          MyClass::getQuestionId, 
          Collectors.toList()
        )
      )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the java8 groupingBy collector. Like this:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class RandomTest {

    class MyClass {
        private Long stackId;
        private Long questionId;

        public MyClass(Long stackId, Long questionId) {
            this.stackId = stackId;
            this.questionId = questionId;
        }

        public Long getStackId() {
            return stackId;
        }

        public Long getQuestionId() {
            return questionId;
        }
    }

    public class MyOtherClass {
        private Long stackId;
        private Set<Long> questionIds;

        public MyOtherClass(Long stackId, Set<Long> questionIds) {
            this.stackId = stackId;
            this.questionIds = questionIds;
        }

        public Long getStackId() {
            return stackId;
        }

        public Set<Long> getQuestionIds() {
            return questionIds;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        List<MyClass> classes = new ArrayList<>();
        List<MyOtherClass> otherClasses = new ArrayList<>();

        //populate the classes list
        for (int j = 1; j <= 25; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                classes.add(new MyClass(0L + j, (100L*j) + i));
            }
        }

        //populate the otherClasses List
        classes.stream().collect(Collectors
                .groupingBy(MyClass::getStackId, Collectors.mapping(MyClass::getQuestionId, Collectors.toSet())))
                .entrySet().stream().forEach(
                longSetEntry -> otherClasses.add(new MyOtherClass(longSetEntry.getKey(), longSetEntry.getValue())));

        //print the otherClasses list
        otherClasses.forEach(myOtherClass -> {
            System.out.print(myOtherClass.getStackId() + ": [");
            myOtherClass.getQuestionIds().forEach(questionId-> System.out.print(questionId + ","));
            System.out.println("]");
        });
    }
}
```