# Converting a list by values to another list with stream

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have the following code which does work. My goal is to get a count of number of nodes that are up and down

```
 Map<Boolean, Long> counting = nodes.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ClusterNode::IsUp,Collectors.counting()));

 List<DataPoint> dps = counting.keySet().stream()
            .map(k -> new DataPoint(timestamp, counting.get(k).toString(), cluster, k.toString()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Wondering if there is a better way to do this using a stream.  Can it be combined into one operation?

Comment: This code cannot work, as it doesn't compile.

Comment: ... And I can see that it still cannot compile, why not just copy-paste your code as-is? And, no, using the stream API, you won't have a better way to do this, perhaps look into the StreamEx library, [refer to this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36445457/1743880).

Comment: what are you doing by second statement?

Comment: the map counting contains a count of the servers that are up and down;  the key is a boolean true/false ( signifying up or down) the value is a count;  The second statement converts that list into 2 DataPoint objects,  which basically contains the timestamp, a key for cluster queried and a key value for server up/down and count;

Comment: @tunaki of course it doesn't compile.  There are some webservice calls prior to this that are completely irrelevant. I have a list of ClusterNode objects and they have a method call idUP() that returns a boolean;

Comment: What I meant, is that `ClusterNode::IsUp()` is illegal... so that cannot be your real code...

Comment: You are right isUP() should be isUp; why be so pedantic. it seems that its not possible to do this in one statement so I will keep it the way it is.

Comment: @JeffreyEllin your 2 statements can be chained. But in terms of redability and simplicity, keeping 2 statements for 2 independent logics is always better. :))

Comment: You can replace `groupingBy` by `partitioningBy`. Further, you followed the anti-pattern of iterating over the `keySet()`, performing an unnecessary lookup in every iteration, instead of iterating over the `entrySet()` in the first place. Not that it matters for the two keys here, but it’s a bad habit that will have a negative impact in other situations. Oh well, if you want to chain both operations, you *have* to iterate over the `entrySet()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your operation as one *statement*, though technically, it consist of two Stream operations:

```
List<DataPoint> dps = nodes.stream()
 .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(ClusterNode::IsUp, Collectors.counting()))
 .entrySet().stream()
 .map(e->new DataPoint(timestamp, e.getValue().toString(), cluster, e.getKey().toString()))
 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You could merge the second operation into the collector as finishing operation, e.g. via `collectingAndThen` and you could also replace the second Stream operation by two lookups of the well-known keys `true` and `false`, then, it would indeed be one Stream operation, however, to no actual benefit.